# Javascript array has no length

Tags: asynchronous, next.js, fetch

I am trying to fetch all nfts from different contracts using THIRDWEB. First I am fetching the contract addresses from sanity (which works perfectly fine) and then I am trying to fetch the nfts (you do it by using the useNFTCollection hook and then use the function getOwned).

Although the array that i receive (dataArray) i can see the elements of it (all the NFTs) but I cannot access any of the elements in the array (it always returns undefined) and i cannot access the length of the array.

[The array looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKYYh.png)

Whereas if i try to grab the length of this array it just returns undefined.

The code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "../../components/Header/Header";
import UserImages from "../../components/Profile/UserImages";
import UserInfo from "../../components/Profile/UserInfo";
import { client } from "../../lib/sanityClient";
import { useNFTCollection } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export async function getServerSideProps({}) {
  const query = `*[_type == "marketItems"]  {
    contractAddress,
  }`;

  const data = await client.fetch(query);

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

function profile({ data }) {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState({});

  const router = useRouter();
  const { wallet } = router.query;
  let dataArray = [];

  if (data[0] !== undefined) {
    if (dataArray === undefined || dataArray.length < 1) {
      dataArray = [];
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const collection = useNFTCollection(data[i].contractAddress);

      async function getNfts() {
        if (collection !== undefined) {
          await collection.getOwned(wallet).then((res) => {
            Promise.all(res).then((values) => {
              for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                dataArray.push(values[i]);
              }
            });
          });
        }
      }
      getNfts();
    }
    console.log(dataArray);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <UserImages />
      <UserInfo />
    </div>
  );
}

export default profile;
```

How can i access the content of dataArray? And how can i assign it to any state variable? Note that I am using this loop this way because useNFTCollection is a Hook, and it does not allow me to use it in any useEffect or useMemo.

Oh and I am using nextJS in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I had to somehow get my data into state, I added a seperate iterator to help me with that (to prevent an infinite loop).

Took me quite long to figure out, it is very simple to create an infinite loop in nextJS/React.